# Adding a wicket WebSocketResource is returning 404

Tags: websocket, wicket

I am new to wicket so bear with me please.

I have created a simple WebSocketResource and added it in an empty page as follow:

```
    @Override
    protected void onInitialize() {
        super.onInitialize();

        add(new BaseWebSocketBehavior(PositionWebSocketResource.NAME));
    }
```

When I try to access the page I keep getting a 404 error:

```
> wicket-websocket-jquery.js?ver=1485085221000:69 WebSocket connection
> to
> 'ws://localhost:8080/wicket/websocket?resourceName=com.try.MyWebSocketResource&wicket-ajax-baseurl=wicket%2Fbookmarkable%2Fcom.try.MyPage%3F0&wicket-app-name=WicketWebSocketFilter'
> failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code:
> 404
```

I updated my Application.java to include the resource:

```
getSharedResources().add(MyWebSocketResource.NAME, new MyWebSocketResource());
```

and the filters:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>WicketWebSocketFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.ws.javax.JavaxWebSocketFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
            <param-value>com.try.Application</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>WicketWebSocketFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which web server ? I don't see anything wrong but better compare your app with the demo application at https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/examples/websocket/

Comment: @martin-g I'm using the maven's tomcat-7 plugin. I just tested it with jetty and it worked. Do you know if tomcat is supported? In the documentation it is mentioned that it is using:
<filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.ws.javax.JavaxWebSocketFilter</filter-class>

I am using Wicket 7.6.0

Comment: Tomcat 7.x is supported only with version 7.0.27+. Maven plugin is not really well maintained though. Better try with a proper Tomcat installation. If it works then report a bug at Tomcat (JIRA component MTOMCAT).

Comment: @O_k: How did you resolve this issue?